# Гугл боты перегружают сервер хоста WP

Tags: wordpress, сервер, нагрузка

Не получается решить проблему, гугл боты перегружают сервер хоста и сайты очень долго грузятся из-за постоянной нагрузки.Уже установил плагин Blackhole for Bad Bots, надеясь что поможет, но нагрузка не падает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что используются гугловские адреса, совсем не значит, что это гугл-бот. Вполне возможно, что кто-то досит ваш сайт с гугловской виртуальной машины

Comment: У меня стоит wordfence , я думал он помогает от ддоса и блокирует Ip адреса. Как мне это исправить или хотя бы проверить?

Comment: Логировать какие именно запросы идут на сайт. Со всеми заголовками. Потом анализировать лог и думать

Comment: файл robots.txt настроен?

Comment: в роботс стоит только блокировка от ботов спамеров.

Comment: попробуйте настроить как показано [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_803/pishem-pravilnyiy-robotstxt-dlya-wordpress.html)